# How to use Fortran intrinsic functions in watch window while debugging?

Tags: visual-studio-2010, fortran

I have a fortran project that I compile with Intel Fortran compiler 2011. Is it possible in Visual Studio 2010 to use intrinsic functions like sum to see the sum of a portion of array  while debugging? For example if I need to see the value of:

```
     sum(qx(1:10,1))
```

when I enter the above string in a watch cell it says: "undefined variable sum".
It seems that it is possible to use functions ( http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/0taedcee.aspx ) but I cannot make it work with intrinsic functions.

thanks
A.

Comment: Is the intrinsic function `sum` defined in a runtime assembly somewhere?

Comment: Honestly I have no idea how to know that.

Comment: I would try opening up the main runtime DLLs under reflector or ILSpy and looking for a sum method.

Answer (score 1):

It is not possible.

The link that you post is not relevant for the Fortran debug expression evaluator.